# What is overriding this css rule?

Tags: css

**How can this situation happen?** (image is from chrome css inspector)

-there is no higher priority rule above

-there is no orange exclamation mark (error)

-I have NOT deactivated it manually in Chrome

[image: how can this happen?]

Computed:

[image: computed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In developer tools, go to `Computed` tab beside `Style` Scroll down and look for those two properties. Expand it and you'll see which file and line number is applied to it

Comment: Updated my original question. Why is it overriding higher tier rules?

Comment: I see it now. It was because of !important. Anyways, thx for suggesting computed tab.

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to answer your question by just looking at that image. The rules for CSS rule cascading are complex. I'll refer you to the spec:

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade

In short: more specific rules override more general ones. Specificity is defined based on how many IDs, classes, and element names are involved, as well as whether the !important declaration was used.

Comment: Yea, but those on top of inspector are the ones with highest priority (top of cascade) so why they are overriden?

Comment: If you put the important in your CSS  it will override the other one, It doesn't matter where the position is. [link] (https://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/)

Answer (score 0):

When the !important keyword is used on a specific property/value pair, it will cause that particular value to escape the cascade and become, as the name suggests, the most important value for that property, overriding any others. [description here](https://www.impressivewebs.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-important-css-declaration/)